# Dedicated Server says This site can't be reached - NodeJs

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, dedicated-server

I have created Node Js API with mongoDB and on port 5000. It is working well in local PC. But when I upload to server and run the program, I am unable to access that API in local PC, it says "This site can't be reached". But the program also running smoothly on server.

The server installed with:
- Node 
- Mongo
- Git
And 
Port 5000 rule added in firewall.

Comment: Have you open `port` 5000 (ingress) in that dedicated server?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Could you browse your server? Like `http://yourserverip:5000`? If not, you must do port forwarding in your server.

Comment: Yes I did but not working. How to do port forwarding?

Comment: your website is working in browser if type `http://yourserverip:5000`?

Comment: `http://yourserverip:5000`  not working. How to do port forwarding, please?

Comment: run following command in your linux server `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 5000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80` It will redirect `5000` to `80` but my advice is to open `5000` in your firewall.

Comment: Thank you I already open on firewall, as I said in my question

Comment: ok, try port redirect as above I mentioned.

Comment: Nice it is working. Why port forwarding? And open 5000 on firewall?

Comment: Because your firewall block `http-port` `5000` probably. Could you mark my answer as correct and upvote please? I've already wrote my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run following command in your linux server `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 5000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80` It will redirect `5000` to `80` but my advice is to open 5000 in your firewall.